# Выбор данных из связующей таблицы по текущей дате

Tags: php, laravel

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать выборку из связующей таблицы по текущей дате?
Например есть таблица менеджеров в которой указаны имя, отдел, общий план.
И есть таблица продаж, в которой есть поля имя, сумма, и выбор менеджера.
Каждый менеджер может сделать несколько продаж.

мне нужно в контроллере получать те продажи которые по текущей дате, за прошлый месяц не показывать.

Я сейчас получаю данные вот так:

```
$managers = Manager::with('sales')->get();
```

И во вьюшке вот так вывожу:

```
@forelse ( $managers as $manager )
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $manager->name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $manager->department }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $manager->overall_plan }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $manager->sales->sum('summa') }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <progress class="progress is-success" id="progress" min="0" max="100" value="{{$manager->sales->sum('summa') / $manager->overall_plan * 100}}">
                                </progress>
                                <span class="percent">{{ round( $manager->sales->sum('summa') / $manager->overall_plan * 100 ) }}&nbsp;%</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @empty
<h3>Нет данных</h3>
                    @endforelse
```

Вот так отображается.
[image: Главная таблица]

Хочется что бы отображались только продажи текущего месяца а прошлые не отображались.

Дело в том что один менеджер может иметь несколько продаж, как мне сделать такой запрос что бы только по текущей дате взять данные?
Или какой еще есть способ более правильный?

Таблица managers имеет отношение hasMany с sales, и sales имеет обратное отношение belongsTo с Manager.

Вот страница менеджеров

[image: Страница менеджеров]

Вот страница продаж
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот форма добавления менеджера
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Форма добавления продажи
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В форме добавления продажи менеджер выбирается с таблицы менеджер.

Comment: Чтобы сделать выборку по продажам за текущий день надо, для начала, хранить дату проведения продажи. И затем извлекать записи в соответствии с этим условием.

Comment: У каждой продажи есть поле created_at, я пытаюсь получить данные исходя из того какая дата. Но пока не получается. Т.е. я получаю все данные вот так: `$managers = Manager::with('sales')->get();` тут у меня коллекция менеджеров, и у каждого менеджера в коллекции есть поле relations, и в нем коллекция модели Sale. У некоторых менеджеров есть несколько продаж. Соотвественно в коллекции менеджеров, есть коллекция с несколькими продажами.Мне нужно пробежаться по ним foreach и в цикле делать логическую проверку по полю created_at у каждой продажи? Вот здесь не могу понять как сделать

Answer (score 1):

А если сделать условие в цикле во вьюве и там отсеивать? То есть примерно так:

```
@forelse ( $managers as $manager )
   @if ($manager->sales->created_at > \Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfDay())
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $manager->name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $manager->department }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $manager->overall_plan }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $manager->sales->sum('summa') }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <progress class="progress is-success" id="progress" min="0" max="100" value="{{$manager->sales->sum('summa') / $manager->overall_plan * 100}}">
                                </progress>
                                <span class="percent">{{ round( $manager->sales->sum('summa') / $manager->overall_plan * 100 ) }}&nbsp;%</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
   @endif
                    @empty
<h3>Нет данных</h3>
                    @endforelse
```

Это если нужны продажи за текущий день.

Comment: Отлично, как вариант тоже можно использовать. Но я решил данный вопрос по другому.

Comment: Мое решение: 1) Добавил в таблицу sales поле month. 2) Во воьюшке создания продажи добавил <input type="hidden" name="month" value="{{ Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('m') }}">.  Далее в поле month попадет текущий месяц. 3)  В котроллере изменил получение данных: $managers = Manager::with(['sales' => function($query) {
            $query->where('month', Carbon::now()->format('m'));
        }])->get(); И все, получаю продажи только текущего месяца и во вьюшке не чего не шаманю с логикой.